# Changing values in a column of a dataframe that satisfy a condition

Tags: r

I am having some trouble with R and would appreciate your help. I have a dataframe with two variables: YearsElapsed and YearsWithout. The first has values of -30, and -21 to 12; the second -12 to 129.

I need to change the value of YearsWithout to -30 when YearsWithot>30 and the corresponding YearsElapsed=-30. (That value indicates the observation is part of my control group.) I tried

```
for (i in 1:5){
if(event_data$YearsElapsed[i]==-30 & event_data$YearsWithout[i]>=30 {
event_data$YearsWithout[i]==-30
  }
}
```

but it didn't make any change.

Suppose event_data has as columns YearsElapsed=c(-30,0,2,14,5) and YearsWithout=c(43,5,16,60,2), as well as other covariates. (Sorry, I wasn't able to upload data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using case_when and mutate from dplyr package:

```
YearsElapsed=c(-30,0,2,14,5)
YearsWithout=c(43,5,16,60,2)
df=data.frame(YearsElapsed, YearsWithout)
library(dplyr)
df=mutate(df, YearsWithout=case_when(YearsElapsed==-30 & YearsWithout >= 30 ~ -30,
                                     TRUE ~ YearsWithout))
```

Output:

```
> df
  YearsElapsed YearsWithout
1          -30          -30
2            0            5
3            2           16
4           14           60
5            5            2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `for` loop for such kind of operations, find the subset of data that you want to change and replace the values.

```
event_data$YearsWithout[event_data$YearsWithout >= 30 & event_data$YearsElapsed ==-30] <- -30
event_data

#  YearsElapsed YearsWithout
#1          -30          -30
#2            0            5
#3            2           16
#4           14           60
#5            5            2
```

**data**

```
event_data <- data.frame(YearsElapsed=c(-30,0,2,14,5), 
                         YearsWithout=c(43,5,16,60,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `=-` instead of  `==-`. The `event_data$YearsWithout[i]==-30` is evaluating a condition, while `event_data$YearsWithout[i]=-30` is assigning a value.

```
if(event_data$YearsElapsed[i]==-30 & event_data$YearsWithout[i]>=30 {
event_data$YearsWithout[i] <- -30
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch of the double equal sign. +1

Comment: I totally missed this myself. Thank you!